# What causes EIO (-5) from dpdk?

Tags: dpdk

Trying to get Intel adapter E810-XXVDA2 to work with VPP (using vfio-pci driver) and cannot figure out the error. When I use the adapter outside of VPP/DPDK, it works just fine (uses ice driver).

Adapter:  Intel(R) Ethernet Network Adapter E810-XXVDA2, driver: vfio-pci
VPP: v22.02
Linux: kernel 5.13.0-40-generic, Ubuntu focal 20.04.3 LTS

When interface is specified in /etc/vpp/startup.conf and started with vppctl:

```
vpp# show hardware-interfaces TwentyFiveGigabitEthernet37/0/0

              Name                Idx   Link  Hardware

TwentyFiveGigabitEthernet37/0/0    1     up   TwentyFiveGigabitEthernet37/0/0

...

    rx bytes ok                                      2613819

    rx missed                                          18468

  Errors:
    rte_eth_dev_start[port:0, errno:-5]: Unknown error -5

  rte_eth_dev_start[port:0, errno:-5]: Unknown error -5
```

What does the -5 (EIO) from dpdk mean? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I was able to get past this error. Going by the suggestion from @VipinVarghese, I turned on logging (which for VPP users means adding `log-level pmd,8` to dpdk section and `default-log-level debug` in logging section of /etc/vpp/startup.conf).

There I saw that there was a second error which needed me to update ice driver. I was at 1.3.4, I moved it to 1.8.8. After that, both errors got resolved.
The errors were:

```
2022/05/04 19:58:48:594 error      dpdk           Interface TwentyFiveGigabitEthernet37/0/0 error -5: Unknown error -5
2022/05/04 19:58:48:594 error      interface      sw_set_flags_helper: dpdk_interface_admin_up_down: Interface start failed
2022/05/04 19:58:48:595 notice     dpdk           ice_tx_queue_start():  >>
2022/05/04 19:58:48:595 notice     dpdk           ice_rx_queue_start():  >>
2022/05/04 19:58:48:595 notice     dpdk           ice_program_hw_rx_queue(): Port (0) - Rx queue (0) is set with RXDID : 22
2022/05/04 19:58:48:595 notice     dpdk           ice_program_hw_rx_queue(): currently package doesn't support RXDID (22)
2022/05/04 19:58:48:595 notice     dpdk           ice_rx_queue_start(): fail to program RX queue 0
2022/05/04 19:58:48:595 notice     dpdk           ice_dev_start(): fail to start Rx queue 0
```

RXDID #22 (ICE_RXDID_COMMS_OVS) was not supported until later versions.

Comment: @schugrove, there are couple of places ICE `EIO` which can be due to `hw->resetting, (hw->tm_conf`, in ice_dcf_dev_start.  In order identify the root cause can you please re-run with eal option `--log-level-pmd,8`. This help to narrow down the issue. Please also update DPDK version, firmware, to ensure we have right settings.

Comment: Thanks Vipin. I am using this device via VPP.

DPDK version (as reported from within VPP): 21.11.0  
As soon as I attempt to start the interface I get an error logged [here](https://github.com/FDio/vpp/blob/90998bc00253730fc640d51e9995e71c2abbd6d0/src/plugins/dpdk/device/common.c#L402)  
DPDK logs (again from within VPP) show...  
`2022/05/04 17:06:47:479 error      dpdk           Interface TwentyFiveGigabitEthernet37/0/0 error -5: Unknown error -5
2022/05/04 17:06:47:479 error      interface      sw_set_flags_helper: dpdk_interface_admin_up_down: Interface start failed`

Comment: Wow.. I really don't know how to format stuff here. Sorry about that.

Comment: let me check this, meanwhile the easiest thing to do is run simple dpdk example app in the same system with `--log-level=pmd,8` since it is dpdk error

Comment: @VipinVarghese, I was able to get past the error (see update above). Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: happy to hear your problem is resolved. To provide completion we can update the answer category as `update of kernel driver and firmware`  this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

DPDK ICE (columibaville E810) PMD can return `EIO` at 2 different places

1. HW or device reset - hw->resetting
2. Traffic Manager configuration - hw->tm_conf

Hence to nail down on the exact problem, always run it with DPDK EAL_INIT option `--log-level=pmd,8`. This will help to capture more details with respect to PMD. I highly recommend to use the appropriate driver and firmware version against the DPDK version as [mentioned in section 25.3](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/ice.html).

[Update] updating the linux driver (which in turn houses the DDP and firmware) has solved the issue for @schugcove.